# Tensorflow: any drawback in setting batch size to None?

Tags: python, tensorflow

It is sometimes advised to let the batch size to None during net creation so that it is not tied to any specific batch size.

My question is, is there any penalty in tensorflow in letting a dimension (batch size, but also could be input width or height for some special nets) unknown until evaluation? Is there any advantage in letting the network know the batch size in advance?

Answer (score 0):

tf.placeholder() does not require you to specify a shape at all.  As you see from documentation, by default a placeholder has no shape at all.

The advantage of setting up a shape is to catch various errors faster. For example this will run without any problems

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], 'a')
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], 'b')
tf.add(a, b)
```

Whereas if you will specify a shape

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3], 'a')
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [5], 'b')
tf.add(a, b)
```

it will complain about incompatible shapes and you will be able to fix your problem fast (imagine having a graph with hundreds of operations, you run it for 3 hours just to find out that there is an error)

Comment: Makes sense, but my question was more specifically targeted at batch sizes, which rarely ever change in a graph. I still don't understand how specifying a batch size would help spotting a mistake.

Comment: @user1735003 as far as I am aware, there is not other advantage of specifying the shape. So if it will not help you to spot a mistake, then you can just leave it as None without any penalty